# Echo form successfull submittted in a new page

Tags: php

I have 2 php files.

The first (add.php) contain a form that submit data into the database with:

```
<form  action="post.php" method="post">
```

The second (post.php) contain just the php code that add the info in the database with:

```
header("location:add.php");
```

Now everything is working (i can add the info in the db and after submission i get redirected to the add.php page), but I was wondering how can I implement a message in this last page that says the recor has been addess successfully?

If I dont use the redirect header location the php code just show me the echo "record addedd successfully but does not redirect me in the form page."

Here the two files...

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect(.................);

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO ..........{
 // echo "Records added successfully.";
    header("location:add-customer.php");
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

and

```
<form  action="post.php" method="post">
.....
.....

 <button type="submit"  name="submit" class="btn btn- default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use url parameters to pass a message in the redirect:

```
//post.php
header("location:add.php?message=submitted");

//add.php

<?php if(isset($_GET['message'])) echo $_GET['message'];?>
<form  action="post.php" method="post">
...
```

Comment: thanks for the tips, it gave me some idea. however i get an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in .......

Comment: it works and its correct but the message it appear in the url, and not in the page (for exemple under the form or as a popup....), So I will try to understand how to modify your tip in this way because thats what i want to achive

Comment: @gigi Well my example should show the message directly above the form, basically where ever you put the line `<?php if(isset($_GET['message'])) echo $_GET['message'];?>`

Comment: I dobble checked it. You are correct and all works fine. thank you

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you